# Multiple conditions in an array

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm having this problem where, when referencing more than a condition in a range, it "doesn't run", the cell is just blank. The expected process for the first condition, for example, was to check if, in the same row, `A2:A="1"` and `B2:B="2"`, if both of these conditions where true, in the same row, it would return `sucess1`.

I'm using Google Sheets, but I think that this might also apply to Excel.

### Code

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(
    AND(A2:A="1", B2:B="2"), "sucess1", 
    AND(A2:A="3", B2:B="4"), "sucess2",
TRUE,))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrayformula does not support `AND` and `OR`. therefore:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A=1)*(B2:B=2), "sucess1", 
              IF((A2:A=3)*(B2:B=4), "sucess2", )))
```

Comment: My real code had actually, 74 `AND`, so in this case I'd have, instead, 74 `IF` and a bunch of parenthesis. Is there any other optimised way to do it so it doesn't have this many characters?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with that formula? or just formula

Comment: Sorry for taking this long! I was editing the testing file. You can see it in Google Sheets [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d5NE1cnU0_PYF723cYBWh4hVPBFvobXOpxM65ACcksk/edit?usp=sharing). The actual formula is in cell `K2`.

Comment: best you can do is L2 - reduced by 293 characters